# Using user input date from one module in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

```
def main():
    userInput()
    calculate()

def userInput():
    print("Please put in the weight of your package:")
    a= input()
    weight= float(a)


def calculate():
    if weight <= 2:
        print('Your rate is $1.10')
    elif weight > 2 or weight <= 6:
        print('Your rate is $2.20')
    elif weight > 6 or weight <= 10:
        print('Your rate is $3.70')
    else:
        print('Your rate is $3.80')
main()
```

So basically I was wondering how can I use the data from the "userInput" module in the "calculate" module. I know that I have the pass an argument, but (and this has been driving me insane) for the life of me I can't figure out the proper way to do it. I understand the concept of arguments, but I cannot implement it in my code in a working matter. Thanks.

Comment: In elif, instead of or, you man need to use and.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the `weight` around as parameters

```
def userInput():
    a= input("Please put in the weight of your package:")
    weight = None
    try:
        weight= float(a)
    except:
        userInput()
    return weight

def calculate(weight):
    if weight <= 2:
        print('Your rate is $1.10')
    elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:
        print('Your rate is $2.20')
    elif weight > 6 and weight <= 10:
        print('Your rate is $3.70')
    else:
        print('Your rate is $3.80')

def main():
    weight = userInput()
    calculate(weight)

main()
```

Comment: Or 'calculate(userInput())' in main function, to eliminate weight variable.

Comment: Yeah. Lots of optimizations are possible, but looks like OP is a beginner. Did not want to confuse too much :) @shantanoo

Comment: Yeah I know I can do it in one module, I just want do it in a certain way by passing an argument as a learning experience you could say. Thanks, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

as an aside you could rewrite the weight checking with:

```
if weight <= 2:
    print('Your rate is $1.10')
elif 2 < weight <= 6:
    print('Your rate is $2.20')
elif 6 < weight <= 10:
    print('Your rate is $3.70')
else:
    print('Your rate is $3.80')
```

note the use of the "n < x < n+" notation

update after comment from shantanoo:

I was looking at the code in the original question:

```
def calculate():
    if weight <= 2:
        print('Your rate is $1.10')
    elif weight > 2 or weight <= 6:
        print('Your rate is $2.20')
    elif weight > 6 or weight <= 10:
        print('Your rate is $3.70')
    else:
        print('Your rate is $3.80')
```

and I realized that on the two elif lines, the first comparisons are not needed, and the code could be rewritten as:

```
def calculate():
    if weight <= 2:
        print('Your rate is $1.10')
    elif weight <= 6:
        print('Your rate is $2.20')
    elif weight <= 10:
        print('Your rate is $3.70')
    else:
        print('Your rate is $3.80')
```

Comment: OP has used or & not and. In case and is used, this is definitely preferred method.